# Why is "." is allowed in query field name but not in table field name in Access?

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access query if we select two field from different table that has the same name. Access automatically uses the combined name in datasheet view like:

```
Select table1.Name, Table1.Address, table2.Name ....
```

becomes

```
table1.Name | Address| table2.Name
```

However, if we try to create a field name with special character "." in a table, it does not allow us to do so. What is the reason for that?

Comment: `table1.Name` is not a field name; it is a table-scoped field name (the field `Name` in table `table1`). It's kind of like getting introduced to someone with "This is Joe from Baltimore", then you going "ooh what a pretty first name" and trying to name your child "Joe from Baltimore Smith" and wondering why people are looking at you strangely.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible because in query it is not actually `name` but `alias` of output field. And you still can not write `SELECT [table1.Name] AS [Name.With.Dots] ...` .